# finding latest entry by JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296347/jpa-select-latest-instance-for-each-item) thread very helpful, but it looks like implementation in the advices are not quite efficient because of the nature of JPA.

I am looking for a solution to pickup latest entry of joining query with grouping, implemented by JPA, so it is not a simple job. My implementation is put "**ORDER BY time DESC**" in the end and pick up the first from return collection, instead of using MAX() function which have to introduce subquery as well, but I wonder is this a good alternative ?

This is the complex query I made by the example from the other example:

```
"SELECT oo FROM Order AS oo WHERE oo.id IN " +
    "(SELECT temp.id FROM " +
        "(SELECT t.order.id AS id, MAX(t.order.orderTime) AS ordTime FROM Transaction t " +
        "WHERE t.order.name= :name " +
        "GROUP BY t.order.name) AS temp" +
    ")";
```

This is the query which I think could be a good alternative but not sure:

```
String query = "SELECT t.order FROM Transaction AS t " + 
    " WHERE t.order.name= :name " +
    " ORDER BY t.order.orderTime DESC";

// and simply just pick up the 1st as the latest entry from result:
Order order =  em.createQueryquery , Order .class).getResultList().get(0);
```

Comment: checking for empty list would be a good idea

Comment: @Denis Tulskiy Will do :) Do you think it is a good practice to find latest entry instead of put everything in a JPQL? I ponder the `ORDER BY DESC` should be reliable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your solution is that it will load ALL entries in a list for you to select one. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6115771/143585) answer, you need to limit result to 1 by calling `query.setMaxResults(1)`. Other than that, it is a perfectly fine solution. You can also use `query.getSingleResult()` to get single entity, but beware of `NoResultException` if there are no such records.